# Automation of VScode project opening in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, automation, console, visual-studio-code

I'm complete beginner with linux (Ubuntu) but I have to use it and I'd like to automate some tasks that I do very often.

What I do:

1. Open VScode and open a project folder
2. Open new VScode window and open another project folder
3. Execute `redis-server` command in console
4. In second VScode window go to Debug and launch first configuration
   and then second configuration (defined in `launch.json` file in
   VSCode)
5. Open a chromium browser and a specific url

What could be the easiest way to achieve it? Are all the steps executable directly from console? Should I use any 3rd-party programs?